# Сomparison of two identical PDF files fails because of trailer

Tags: java, pdf, junit, mocking

I am new here and a bit experienced in Java.
I create simple unit-test were I download some pdf-file and try to compare it with my local file.

```
        final byte[] content = mockMvc.perform(
                get(URL, SAMPLE_1_ID)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();

        final byte[] expectedContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src\\test\\resources\\my-local-file.pdf"));

        assertThat(content).isEqualTo(expectedContent);
```

I am trying to compare two PDF files that absolutely identical, but when I use byte comparison, this gives me:

```
Expected :[B@1b708791
Actual   :[B@42e6e4b6
```

Actually, I tried to find what was wrong and found this (when using the String output format (`.getContentAsString()`))

In first file:

```
trailer
<</Info 7 0 R/ID [<435536b10a5043b4c9e7a580fddc1aad><0c71af32c6741a3e5d5b226eb852934a>]/Root 6 0 R/Size 8>>
startxref
3274
%%EOF
```

And in second file:

```
trailer
<</Info 7 0 R/ID [<af96b826e05e3a7d865b83646cae3b40><98b845965d6bf45ee9a8faf6f6be9981>]/Root 6 0 R/Size 8>>
startxref
3274
%%EOF
```

As you can see ID's different, and that's why I have assertion-fail

I found that the identifier is generated unique for each document:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/developing-with-pdf/9781449327903/ch01.html

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPpfG.png)

So, I have no idea how I can compare this two files.

By default, I can't modify response, so maybe I can use something smarter than byte-to-byte comparison, something that can recognize the file-content and use only it.

Answer (score 1):

Google suggests that you should render the PDF as image and compare the images like this library does:

- https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/wiki/Testing-Your-PDF-Document-Output

There are more flexible solutions like this library:

- http://www.pdfunit.com/

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Unfortunately, in my project I was forced to use only already implemented libraries, and luckily for me I found one proper to manage my issue)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody interested I found one possible solution for me. I used library`com.itextpdf` provided by

- https://itextpdf.com/ru

  which was already implemented in our project.

This, the solution I used:

```
        final byte[] content = performRequestToDownloadPdfReport(SAMPLE_1_ID); 
        final PdfReader reader_on_actual_content = new PdfReader(content);
        final String actual_parsed_content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader_on_actual_content, NumberUtils.INTEGER_ONE);

        final PdfReader reader_on_expected_content = new PdfReader("src/test/resources/sample-history-report.pdf");
        final String expected_parsed_content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader_on_expected_content, NumberUtils.INTEGER_ONE);

        assertThat(actual_parsed_content).isEqualTo(expected_parsed_content);
```

In my ex. I have *.pdf file with only 1 page, so I can use `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage()` to extract needed content and compare it with expected.